# Is there a way to 'back up' in the campaign in Borderlands 2?

Tags: borderlands-2

I must have played with a friend who was further than I in the campaign at some point because I just recently reached a point in the game where I was asked this question;

> Do you wish to skip over the missions you've completed in other play sessions or continue as normal?

I chose to continue, as I can't remember anything I've done with anyone else, its been too long. No problems, except about 5 minutes later I accidentally moved ahead too far, too fast, and skipped some dialogue I actually *wanted* to hear.

To solve this issue, my plan of action was to end-task to skip the auto-save process, and redo the mission and listen to the dialogue. Upon starting the game up, instead of starting at the beginning of the mission, I started at what I **think** is the end of all the missions it originally asked if I wanted to skip.

Is there any way to fix this? I'm playing on PC.

Comment: Do you want the real way or the "forced" way.  The forced involving Gibbed's editor

Comment: @memescientist wh not both ?

Comment: Please note whether PC or console....

Comment: @FrankV Edited or not, last sentence states this: "_I'm playing on PC._"

Comment: @Sebie - The last sentence wasn't there 7 hours ago when Frank wrote that comment

Comment: @Robotnik Ok, fair enough all I posted it because it would trigger a notification for Frank so he knows.

Comment: @Robotnik but I like my snark :( lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only certain quests that can be "reset". These quests are only the bosses at the end of the game or a DLC. To reset these quests, just follow the ! mark and start the quest like any other.

I found this [save editor video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QPk04gdOMkc) if you want to use a save editor to modify your save file. In the description of the save editor video, you'll find these 3 links that will show you how to do this for each of the platforms.

Xbox Save Extraction ►

PS3 Save Extraction►

Gibbed Save editor► http://blog.gib.me/

Comment: So to clarify, if I'm not at a particular boss then I'm kinda screwed?

Comment: Kind of, yes. This is an issue that a lot of people have with borderlands. If you want, you can always join an online game where someone is on a quest that you want to do. But that's about all you can do.